# Set repeated field attributes using form_row

Tags: symfony, twig

I have created my own theme for form_row and set it to be used globally on the app, it looks like this:

**fields.html.twig**

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}

  {% set class="form-row" %}
  {% if attr.class is defined %}
    {% set class = class ~ ' ' ~ attr.class %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if not form.vars.valid %}
    {% set class = class ~ ' error' %}
  {% endif %}

  <div class="{{ class }}" >
    {% if (label is defined) and (label is same as(false)) %}
      {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {% else %}
      {{ form_label(form) }}
      {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
  </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Then I have overrided the FOSUserBundle registration form:

**register_content.html**

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
  {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'form.placeholder.email'|trans}, 'label': false }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.username, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'form.placeholder.username'|trans}, 'label': false }) }}

    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'form.placeholder.password'|trans}, 'label': false }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'form.placeholder.password_confirmation'|trans}, 'label': false }) }}
    <div>
      <ul class="no-bullet">
        <li><input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" class="button radius expand" /></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="facebook button radius expand">Sign Up with Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="twitter button radius expand">Sign Up with Twitter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
  <p class="text-center">Already signed up? <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">{{ 'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a></p>
</form>
```

What I'm not able to do is to pass attributes to the form.plainPassword but just using one form_row() call, is this possible?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
{{ form_row(form.plainPassword, {
    'first': { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'form.placeholder.password'|trans}, 'label': false },
    'second': { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'form.placeholder.password_confirmation'|trans}, 'label': false }
})}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as far as I know, but it doesn't seem necessary for your use case. Just create a second [unmapped](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#mapped) field with the [data attribute](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#data) set to be identical to the mapped password field.